# How to remove elements from HTML/Change the page entirely?

Tags: css, html

I am using the following tag to load my scripts and start the game I am making, but all the original elements stay from the original webpage.

```
<input type="image" src="Images/start.jpg" height='200' width='350' alt='Something went wrong loading the images. Update your Internet plugins and try again.' onclick='INIT_THREE(); INIT_CANNON(); UPDATE();'/>
```

Is there any way to remove the elements like the background sound and image when I press the button? I tried using href to load another html page, but I don't think that is the best way to do it, plus it didn't work. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question was likely downvoted because you haven't showed the code you tried, and because you didn't mention that you need help with javascript/jQuery (the only solution to interact with users). However, we all start at the beginning and I remember, not that long ago, when I was where you are now. So, don't be discouraged -- keep asking questions and don't pay any attention to downvotes. Just try to improve - but keep learning. And keep asking questions. Arglab gave an excellent answer below - note that you must include the jQuery library (as he did). And learn jQuery, asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remove() (jQuery)

Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use `.detach()` instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "button" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).remove();
  });
});
```

```css
p {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hello</p>
how are
<p>you?</p>
<button>Call remove() on paragraphs</button>
```

Removes all paragraphs that contain "Hello" from the DOM. Analogous to doing

```
$("p").filter(":contains('Hello')").remove().
```

From https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Excellent answer. Well done. +1

Comment: Sorry I took so long to get back, I took a basic jQuery course and I can see what I was missing out on. Thanks for pointing an amateur in the right direction!